# How to find the path after "cannot find module" message when I try to use grass tools in qgis

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I use mac and when I try to use grass modules in qgis (brighton) I get a "cannot find module" message.

Comment: Have you tried Uninstall and install again? Please elaborate your question e.g. Are you in windows or not, all the other model is working etc?

Answer (score 1):

He uses a Mac. For the procedure, look at [Configuring external applications](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html).

Check the path in Processing/Toolbox/Options/Providers/GRASS...

- If you use the [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/) version, there is a GRASS GIS 6.x version integrated in the QGIS application bundle and the path is `/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass`
- if you want to use another version of GRASS GIS, adapt the path, for example `/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS`for GRASS 6.x and `/Applications/GRASS/GRASS-7.x.app/Contents/MacOS`for GRASS 7

If you use another version of QGIS (Homebrew, MacPorts, ...), it is the same thing

Comment: I don't find the tab called processing, where is that one?

Comment: You need to activate the processing extension in Plugins/ Manage and Install Plugins ([Using Plugins](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/using_plugins.html))

Comment: Thank you! The "processing" plugin gives this info: "This plugin is broken
No module named general" 
Is it possible to fix?

Comment: How have you installed QGIS  ?

Comment: I downloaded the suggested files and drivers from qgis-hompage and installed qgis.

Comment: Therefore, you have a problem because the module named general is the script /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py