# Error opening GRASS mapset in QGIS?

Tags: grass-7.0, qgis-2.18

I have installed Grass 7.0.5 but I cannot open a mapset via QGIS 2.18. I receive this error message:

```
Cannot open the mapset. Mapset lock failed (exitStatus=1, exitCode=0, errorCode=1, error=Process crashed stdout=, stderr=dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libgrass_gis.7.0.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
)
```

If I create a new mapset instead of opening one, the error reads "New mapset successfully created, but cannot be opened:" and then the rest of the error as above.

I am running Mac OSX El Capitan, and I have already disabled SIP. I also encountered, and solved, [Problems finding GRASS module after upgrading QGIS (Mac)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219808).

Can this latest problem be solved, or should I revert to Grass 6?

Comment: Try to create mapset from grass7. It may be a grass issue.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I can't even open Grass 7 on its own.

"Terminal got an error: Can't open window 1. (-1728)"

Comment: I have similar issues. Grass won't open on its own. Also when I make a new mapset it crashes QGIS

Comment: sudo ln -s /Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libintl.8.dylib /usr/local/lib

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Giving a line of code without any context or explanation does not answer the question at all.  Please **[edit]** your answer to explain where to use that code, how to use it, and what it does.  Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score -1):

When I met the same problem, I was able to solve it by commanding:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libintl.8.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

In your case, didn't it help?