# Using GRASS 7 in QGIS 2.18 on MacOS

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-2, mac, version-control

Does anybody found a way to use GRASS 7 in QGIS 2.18 under MacOS?

QGIS 2.18.19-2 is the latest version packaged with GRASS 7. For many reasons, all the following versions been have packaged with GRASS 6 only. But the tools are unusable with this version because they are compatible with version 7 only.

I tried to copy the GRASS 7 folder from QGIS 2.18.19-2 into `/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass7` in my 2.18.28 version, but it doesn't to work.

QGIS gives me an error, it cannot find `default.qgc` in `/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass7/default.qgc`

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the Processing Toolbox in QGIS, click "enable additional providers".
A Window called Processing options opens. Under Providers, GRASS GIS 7 commands, make sure the Activate box is ticked and the path to your Grass installation is correctly mentioned.
Screenshots on my system:

[image]
[image]

Restart your QGIS and check if your tools are working now.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.
Unfortunately, it says my Grass installation is invalid 

Comment: https://i430.photobucket.com/albums/qq28/M-Rick/Capture%20dcran%202019-02-25%20%2023.02.05_zps2iraqmes.png

http://i430.photobucket.com/albums/qq28/M-Rick/Capture%20dcran%202019-02-25%20%2023.01.42_zpsepfeoisc.png

http://i430.photobucket.com/albums/qq28/M-Rick/Capture%20dcran%202019-02-25%20%2023.01.46_zpsvgmb1mnp.png

Comment: Perhaps this related link could help your further? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219808/finding-grass-module-after-upgrading-qgis-mac?rq=1
Otherwise I'd just try uninstalling both QGIS and GRASS and then reinstall again.